# In iOS subscriptions, is there a limit on how often verifyReceipt can be called per day/hour/etc?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

Based on my understanding of how subcriptions work, it seems like we should build some sort of cron job to check if almost about to expire users were renewed since notifications won't be sent in some cases.

Based on reading these:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-SUBSCRIPTIONS-MY_SERVER_PROCESS_RARELY_RECEIVES_RENEWAL_NOTICES_WHEN_THE_AUTO_RENEWING_SUBSCRIPTION_RENEWS_

https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscriptions-are-hard-d9b29c74e96f

my question is:

1. is my conclusion true? are notifications not sent for renewals?
2. if I have to build a cron job and call verifyReceipt myself I can imagine that I would call it quite a lot per day, is there a limit to how many times I can call this endpoint? When will I be throttled?

Answer (score 2):

Notifications are not sent for regular renewals. You *will* get a notification (INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL) if the user cancels and resubscribes. Best practice would be to check the `/verifyReciept` endpoint to get subscription status from Apple. There aren't any published throttles on this endpoint and would imagine it's extremely scalable.

Also, highly recommend [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/) to completely manage subscription status for you.